Retrieve wait stats for an old query?
I know I can get wait stats about "current" queries via their SPID in sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats but the SPID is recycled into new sessions.
Is there a way to query these stats for queries a few days old, when their SPID has been reused...?
I am using SQL 2019

no , you need to have a monitoring system in place that you can refer to for these cases , sql server is not tracking/logging these stuff as far as I know

If you have query store enabled you can get some aggregated info from sys.query_store_wait_stats - (both aggregated in terms of lumping stats for different executions of the same query plan together and in lumping different wait types together into broader categories)
